# Ionic 2 and Angular 2 on a same project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a simple question (i think ?)

I will start a new project for a mobile app, and an other developper  wants to create the project with angular 2 CLI.

I get that Ionic 2 is build ON Angular 2, so there is no use if we want to do a mobile app to put Angular 2 (with bootstrap) AND Ionic 2 in the same project ?

Only the use of Ionic 2 is sufficient no ?

If this is not clear don't hesitate to let me know !

Thank you in advance to the community !

Comment: It should be noted that ionic 2 is making grounds in a web/desktop focused approach. Technically you can use the an ionic base for your web applications and they have updated the [grid](http://blog.ionic.io/build-awesome-desktop-apps-with-ionics-new-responsive-grid/) view and are working on a [split pane](http://blog.ionic.io/testing-split-pane-support/) for the menu to auto adjust for wider screens. There has also been a lot work on [pwa](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-pwa-support-in-ionic-2/) making usability as a web application really nice.

Comment: OK, this mean that more and more we will be able to only use ionic 2 on a project that contain a web app for computer, and apps for ios and android (and windows phone). This is great !! 
I didn't know about that, i ll take a look on how to implement the two different view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both codebases are trying to achieve the same thing (i.e. have the same data/service layers), then you have a few options.

1. First build an Angular 2 app, then fork it and build a Ionic 2 mobile app from it. You will have to do some modifications to make it fit to Ionic 2, but it will not be too bad. **You should choose this option if you can build things sequentially.**
2. Build a shared repository with the model/service/data layer and have the two projects maintain their own view concurrently. **You should choose this option if you have to build things concurrently.** This will probably be a bit harder to set up.
3. Build an Angular2 app and then just wing it with Apache Cordova to re-use the same view. **I would strongly suggest against this**, since Ionic's view implementation is much nicer and cleaner than what you would come up with.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment and explicite one.

Angular 2 is strongly used for webapp single page app, i don't really see the point to have it their to build a mobile app no ? I'm new to Ionic so maybe i'm missing some point ?

I really like your option 2, maybe i ve missed someting and they want :
1. A web app for computer
2 An app for mobile

It's from my point of view the more evident thing to do.

Comment: Ionic2 is an adaptation of Angular2 for mobile. In a way mobile apps ARE single-page web-apps (adapted for mobile). So this is what Ionic does. It then wraps your single-page webapp in a webview and puts it in an app wrapper.

Comment: Thank you ! This is what i understood but i was not sure of it. Good day @Ajk_P

Comment: @Ajk_P can i know more details, I'm working on angular project but now trying to get ionic framework in my existing application. Can u please give me some more information.
i have open a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925350/ionic-framework-in-existing-angular4-project