# Ionic framework in existing Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working in angular project with own CSS which is almost done now i want to use ionic framework with cordova in my project. I tried but it is not working .

Is there any way and step by step process to add ionic framework in my existing Angular 4 project.

can i have any link or guidance to reach my goal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

There is a schematic command for adding ionic to an existing angular project:

`ng add @ionic/angular`

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the following errors:

‘ion-card’ is not a known element:

If ‘ion-card’ is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If ‘ion-card’ is a Web Component then add ‘CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA’ to the ‘@NgModule.schemas’ of this component to suppress this message.ng

Answer (score 11):

I have documented my approach here:

https://stack247.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/integrate-ionic-in-existing-angular-project/

This applies to

- Angular 7.
- Ionic 5.

Essentially, these are the steps:

The step includes creating a new project using Ionic CLI, I'm going to refer it as Ionic project while my original Angular project as, well, Angular project.

- In your Angular project, update all npm packages, to the latest major if you can. This is to avoid version conflict with Ionic project's npm packages.
- Start a new Ionic blank project.

  ```
  ionic start project-name blank
  ```
- Update all npm packages in the newly created Ionic project.
- Copy `ionic.config.json` from Ionic project to Angular project.
- Copy `angular.json` from Ionic project to Angular project.

  - If you have specifically changed anything in your `angular.json`, make that necessary changes in the Angular project after the copy.
  - Ionic uses SCSS for style sheet by default, so if you are not using SCSS, make sure to copy settings under `projects/app/architect/**/options/styles` from Angular project's `angular.json` prior to copy.
- Copy `package.json` from Ionic project to Angular project.

  - If you have specifically changed anything in your `package.json` (npm scripts, etc), make that necessary changes in the Angular project after the copy.
  - Combine the npm packages from both projects setting under `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.
- Combine .gitignore files from both projects, if you are using Git source control.
- In Angular project, delete `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder. These should be located in root of the project.
- In Angular project, run npm install command.

  ```
  npm install
  ```
- Test and make sure everything runs.

  ```
  // Test run with Ionic
  ionic serve
  // Test run with Angular
  ng serve --open
  ```
- If you want to prepare your project for Cordova, runs the following command. Note that environment setup is required. Please refer to reference section for more details.

  ```
  // For Android
  ionic cordova prepare android
  // For iOS
  //ionic cordova prepare ios
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have a question. Do we also have to copy the ionic scripts contained in the ionic package.json? Because without that, it says "ionic cordova prepare android" can only be run in ionic configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this. I only wish to add that if your project has a name other than `app`, that will need to be specified to the `serve` command. `ionic serve --project=myCustomProjectName`

Comment: @AnkitJoshi Yes, you do.

Comment: @stack247 Great! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Below Solution work for me: (I've added ionic in angular project with below steps)

- **Step 1:**

> ionic init

[image]

- **Step2**

> ng add @ionic/angular

[image]

- ***Step 3: (While build or run (ionic build/ ionic serve) your project you will see below error)***

[image]

To resolve above error follow below steps:

1. Open angular.json file:
2. change below properties

   2.1 **Before**: *outputPath: 'dist/<<project_name>>/browser'*
   **After**: *outputPath: 'www'*

   2.2 Replace <<PROJECT_NAME>> with "app". For Example: **Before**: *'my_angular_project:build:production'* **AFTER**: *'app:build:production'*

**output**
[image]

> ***In case if you are facing scrolling issue***

In ***project_name>src>style.css*** add below css properties

```
html, body {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Ionic components in an existing Angular project. Two easy steps:

Add schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] to your module (app.module.ts)
Like so:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  schemas:      [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Add a link to the CDN in your index.html

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@5.0.0/dist/ionic.js"></script>
```

Source:
https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/use-ionic-components-as-web-components-in-angular-2eee2178d5be