# Is it possible to use Ionic 4 inside an Angular 8 project using ng serve?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Is it possible to launch an Angular 8 application which uses Ionic 4 components using the ng serve command?

I tried setting up a completely fresh Angular 8 application and installed Ionic 4 framework afterwards. Now i want to launch the application using Ionic 4 components using ng serve. Is it even possible?

Here are my dependencies:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^8.2.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.8.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ionic cli mostly just wraps around angular cli commands. Any ionic project can be run using `ng` commands as well as ionic - it is the build scripts that have additional logic, and so if you want full use of these you will have to modify your `angular.json` file to add the relevant bindings. The easiest way will be to copy from an ionic starter project.

You can see the full steps taken in a similar question for angular 7: [Ionic framework in existing Angular 4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925350/ionic-framework-in-existing-angular-4-project)